# How to set attributes to a mock request inside a J2EE filter which are available in a unit test written for the filter

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, servlet-filters, easymock

I have a filter class called `SomeFilter` which implements `javax.servlet.Filter`.
In doFilter method, I set an attribute "someResult" with key "key" and value "result".

I have a Unit Test class called `TestSomeFilter` which invokes the doFilter of `SomeFilter`. Now the problem is that the request attribute "someResult" that I set in the filter, does not get set. This only happens when I am Unit Testing (on local) i.e. the request is a mock request. If I deploy the filter on websphere application server (on local), then the attribute is set correctly. Also, the setAttribute of the `MockedRequestWrapper` does not get invoked when I run the Unit Test in debug mode.

The code is given below.

I would really appreciate if someone could help me out by providing a solution to my issue or at least pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

CODE:

```
public class SomeFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter {

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, 
                   ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) 
    throws ServletException {

    //do some stuff

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

    Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("key","result");

    request.setAttribute("someResult",map);
    chain.doFilter(request, res);
    }
}

public class TestSomeFilter {

    @org.junit.Test
    public void testSomeFilter {
        HttpServletRequest mockRequest = null;
        HttpServletResponse mockResponse = null;
        HttpSession mockSession = null;
        MockedRequestWrapper mrw = null;

        org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(mockSession);
        org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(mockRequest);
        org.easymock.EasyMock.replay(mockResponse);

        mrw = new MockedRequestWrapper(mockRequest);

        filter.doFilter(mrw, mockResponse, mockFilterChain);

        HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String,String>) mrw        
                                         .getAttribute(("someResult");

        String value = map.get("key");

        org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(
            "The output should be result.", 
            "result", value);
    }

    @org.junit.Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        mockRequest = createNiceMock(HttpServletRequest.class);
        mockResponse = createNiceMock(HttpServletResponse.class);
        mockSession = createNiceMock(HttpSession.class);
    }

    @org.junit.After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {}

    public class MockedFilterChain implements FilterChain {

        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, 
                        ServletResponse response) 
                    throws ServletException {}
    }
}

public class MockedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private Map<String,Object> m = null;
    public MockedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
            super(httpServletRequest);
    }

    public void setAttribute(String name, Object o){            
        m = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        m.put(name, o);         
    }

    public Object getAttribute(String name){
        return m.get(name);//<<<< PROBLEM: This map is always null causing NPE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. The wrapper class needs to be modified like this:

```
public class MockedRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private Map<String,Object> m = null;
    private HttpServletRequest origReq = null;

    public MockedRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) 
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        super(httpServletRequest);
        origReq = httpServletRequest;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAttribute(String name, Object o){            
        m = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        m.put(name, o);
        super.setAttribute(name, o);
        origReq.setAttribute(name, o);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttribute(String name){
        if(m != null){
            return m.get(name);
        } else if(origReq.getAttribute(name) != null){
            return origReq.getAttribute(name);
        } else {
            return super.getAttribute(name);
        }
    }
}
```